# Customize Scaffolding templates list

Tags: t4, scaffolding

Is there any way to customize the controller scaffolding template list, like adding different kind of options to use different kind of templates?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

how we could add the Scaffold environment so that it will be available in "Scaffolding options" of Add Controller dialog box?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I prefer creating my own scaffolders and use them from nuget, but you can modify the scaffolding options by adding CodeTemplate folders to your solution. See Hanselmans tutorial [about modifying codetemplates](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ModifyingTheDefaultCodeGenerationscaffoldingTemplatesInASPNETMVC.aspx)